# Converting Celsius to Fahrenheit and Vice Versa in Delphi

Tags: delphi

I am Studying Delphi, For some reason they use this old language but any case.
I need to build a Weather application that Converts Celsius And Fahrenheit.

The user has to enter 7 days Weather but This example I just want to figure out Day 1

So I have first of all created Radio buttons to Choose Celsius and Fahrenheit,
Then if they choose Celsius I have to Convert Celsius to Fahrenheit and if they choose Fahrenheit I have to Convert it to Celsius.

So This is my Code:

```
 var
   Celsius, Fahrenheit, Day1 : Double;

 begin
   Day1 := fedDay1;
   Celsius := (Day1 - 32)*5/9;
   Fahrenheit := Day1 * 9/5 + 32;

   if radCelsius.checked then
     lblConvertDay1.Caption := FloatToStrF(Fahrenheit, ffFixed, 15, 2);
   else
     lblConvertDay1.Caption := FloatToStr(Celsius, ffFixed, 15, 2);
   end;
```

It gives an Error on fedDay1  This is a Floating Spin Edit

Help please

Comment: *It gives an Error on fedDay1* The language might be old, but I'm sure that it gives a proper error message with informative details. Please try harder next time to supply all the details.

Comment: Among other problems already pointed out, you cannot have ; before else.  But the compiler should have told you that.

Comment: Gosh, now being old is a bad thing? I sort of like the maturity that comes with it... :-)

Comment: A "newer" language isn't going to make you a better programmer. But what will make you a better programmer (in any language) is reading your error messages and trying to understand what they're telling you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign the SpinEdit to the variable directly. You have to use the value.

```
Day1 := fedDay1.Value;
```

Your code has to only do the conversion needed, as `Day1` will already have one of them. So if the user entered a Celsius value, you only need to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit. If they entered a Fahrenheit value, you only need to convert from Fahrenheit to Celsius.

```
var
  Day1: Double;
  OutVal: Double;
begin
  Day1 := fedDay1.Value;
  if radCelsius.checked then
    OutVal := (9.0 / 5.0) * Day1 + 32     // Cels. entered; convert to Fahrenheit 
  else
    OutVal := (5.0 / 9.0) * (Day1 - 32);  // Fahr. entered; convert to Celsius
  lblConvertDay1.Caption := FloatToStr(OutVal, ffFixed, 15, 2);
end;
```

If you're using a recent version of Delphi (Delphi 2007 has them, and they may go as far back as Delphi 5), the `StdConvs` unit has predefined functions you can use for the conversions:

```
implementation

uses
  StdConvs;

   if ...
      OutVal := CelsiusToFahrenheit(Day1)
   else
      OutVal := FahrenheitToCelsius(Day1);
```

Answer (score 3):

The right way to solve the problem is to create a function to convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit, and another to convert in the opposite direction.

```
function CelsiusFromFahrenheit(const Fahrenheit: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := (Fahrenheit-32.0)/1.8;
end;

function FahrenheitFromCelsius(const Celsius: Double): Double;
begin
  Result := Celsius*1.8 + 32.0;
end;
```

The main error in your code is that `fedDay1` is not a floating point value, but a GUI control. So you need to read the value out of the control with `fedDay1.Value`.

Then you can write your GUI update code much more cleanly:

```
InputValue := fedDay1.Value;
if radCelsius.checked then
  ConvertedValue := FahrenheitFromCelsius(InputValue)
else
  ConvertedValue := CelsiusFromFahrenheit(InputValue);
lblConvertDay1.Caption := FloatToStrF(ConvertedValue, ffFixed, 15, 2);
```

Comment: +1 I answered the immediate problem, but the functions are a better future solution. I would have named them differently, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Ken I like it that way round because it works well at the call site. Consider `ConvertedValue := FahrenheitFromCelsius(InputValue)`. The output value is positioned right next to its units (Fahrenheit), and the input value is also positioned right next to its units (Celsius). I am also a huge advocate for giving functions the name that describes their return value and making sure that the function has no side-effects. Of course, it's always what you are used to.

Comment: @David, if OP has one of the recent Delphi versions, you're [`reinventing the wheel`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18660520/960757).

Comment: @TLama I know that. The asker is a student, and I judge that learning how to structure code is the most important thing. The answer was meant to be in didactic style.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Guys!  and Ken White, the error was saying it is an overloaded function or something.  I will have a look at all the code replies, Thanks so much!

Comment: Error messages never say "or something". Be precise and read the messages carefully.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign the spinner to the double. You need to get the value from it.

Try:

```
Day1 := fedDay1.Value;
```

Comment: That's right! Anyway, the code will fail to compile also on the `;` terminator before `else` keyword.

Comment: As opposed to some languages such as VisualBasic, which does support default properties. But Delphi doesn't have such support (except for dynamic arrays)

Comment: @JerryDodge You don't mean dynamic arrays. You mean [*default array properties*](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Properties#Array_Properties).

Comment: @David Yes, I shouldn't type much before I've finished my morning coffee

Answer (score 1):

You have the function [CelsiusToFahrenheit](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.StdConvs.CelsiusToFahrenheit). Your code needs some modifications in order to have a functional application.

Comment: I havent learned about functions yet, im sure I could use them but im not sure how they work so I will stick with the basic method that Ken Provided!